# Login through FB Giving Error iOS Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone-developer-program

[I have integrated FB in my project, when i am going to login in by pressing Login with FB button it is showing this error "click here to see the error" i have attached url image please have a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tQ0n.png)

Comment: Just logout Facebook from your browser and remove browser from background and then again try to login from your app .

Comment: @Moni_BQ i am testing on simulator i have logged out from simulator and browser both then too showing soo.

Comment: Then check your app key in plist.

Comment: Reset your simulator and try again

Comment: Add transport security in plist file

Comment: yes i have added Transport security and also reset my simulator.. again damn showing the same same.

Comment: i have created a new app for fb and its Appid works for me. thanks @Moni_BQ